# centering the four divs inside a div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center the contents of the container divs inside which will have four div's  alignned 2 divs in a row, but it is not getting centered.

Not sure why this happens in google chrome and other browsers.

Below is the code, please help.

**CSS:**

```css
.container{
  margin: auto;
  width:80%;
  height:900px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
 }

.column, .columns {
  float:left;
  min-height:1px;
  padding:0 15px;
  position:relative
}

section#{
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
  background: url(../images/sidebar_shadow.png) repeat-y left top;
  float: left;
  margin-top: -2px;
 }

.button.largebutton {
  min-width:400px;
  min-height:300px;
  float:left;
  margin: 60px;
 }
```

**PHP**

```php
 <section id="main" class="column">
    <h1 class="info_bar">My Surveys</h1>
    <div class="container"> //contents of this div to be centered
        <?php include 'tabcontainer_surveyholder.php'; ?>  //pulls the four divs 
    </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: Add more code, Your question references a php file, what happens there?

Comment: Do you want it aligned center to vertical or horizontal? Or both?

Comment: what is inside your php file. what are the classes of divs inside the container. ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution to this is:

Wrap the 4 div's in a wrapper. See the width of the wrapper in console and then write following css:

```
.wrapper{ position:relative;
          left:50%; 
          margin-left:-(half of its total width);
}
```

here is a codepen

[click me](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HDIBJ)

Comment: If I do this it dose not center in the IE?? not sure what to do?please help....I am using percentage instead of px in the wrapper... .wrapper {position:relative; width:80%; left:50%; margin-left:-40%;float:left;}

Comment: I checked it just now.. It's working fine till IE8. Share a screenshot if you see a problem.